# how to perform some task on exit of application(normal or abnomal) in android?

Tags: android

friends,

i want to delete file data that i have created in android application.

if my application is terminated abnomally or nomally?

any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: But you can't count on onDestroy being called.

The better strategy is to make sure you have cleaned up data when your app next starts.

Comment: yes you are right application does not close in android phone so i did not find any event like that but onDestory() for each activity is still there.

Comment: Down vote 2 years after the answer without comment - I'll just remove the answer, then the question becomes useless.